# PHP convert date to mm-dd-YYYY to YYYY-mm-dd

Tags: php, html, date, timestamp

My problem is that when I try to save in my database a date I receive this date: `1970-01-01`

This is my html code:

```
<input type="text" name="dob" value="<?php echo $rows['dob']; ?>" required title="The Date of Birth is required" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](19|20)\d\d"></input>
```

And this my php code to get the value:

```
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
echo $dob.'<br>';
$dob_new = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dob));
echo $dob_new.'<br>';
```

This is the result:

```
01-22-1984
1970-01-01
```

The first date is one example that a date that the user can enter and the second date is the result of the conversion!

The mystery is that sometimes this work but sometimes no... so what happen here? Any suggestion? Any error in my code?

Comment: Can we see all the code? It'd help isolate the problem.

Comment: Seems that you are doing things the hard way. Rather than `<input type="text">` you should be using `<input type="date">` so that the date is formatted properly every time. Another good option is to use 3 drop down menus that are pre-populated with possible days, months, and years. This way you can control the formatting.

Comment: EternalHour I appreciate your advice but I need that this field be a text because I'm filling this field with a database query and when I try to fill a date field nothing happen! that's the reason that I'm using type=text.

Comment: The date type supports the `value` attribute, you should have no trouble populating it from the database if the format is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use dashes as your date separator PHP assumes European date format which is DD-MM-YYYY. Yours is MM-DD-YYYY. As a result [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) thinks it has an invalid date and returns false which causes `date()` to return the date you are seeing which is the Unix Epoch.

To work around it you either need to send the date in the correct format or use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the date properly.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $_POST['dob']);
$dob_new = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/315078)

Comment: John When I try your code I have this error:  Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\....

Comment: Show the date you are using in that example

Comment: I 'm adding for example just this simple date:   01-22-1984

Comment: Click on the demo button. That shows it you it working for that date. I think you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: Nothing my friend in your demo it work properly but in my project I put the same lines and I receive this error!  please any suggestions?  Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string....... the error is when I try to save that date in the database

Comment: @abelvf Add error reporting to the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` Also update your question with the code which you use now with the provided answer and what errors you get! Also mark the line which produces the error with a comment in the question

Comment: @abelvf If you are trying to save `$date` in the database it won't work. You must call format() first and save that value to a variable. Then you can save that variable to the database.